# Python list and tuple Unpacking

Tags: python, list, tuples

thanks for answering me at the first..
I have a **List** or a **Tuple** in Python; try to unpack instead of index like below:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
first,second,third,fourth = list1
```

now its ok if I use it like this:

> `first` ====> it will return **1**

but when I use it inside [ ] its like below:

> `list1[first]` ====> it will return **2**

seams it wont count [0] index in this mod!!
why? and how to fix?

Comment: Python lists/tuples are 0-indexed i.e. indexing starts from 0.

Comment: `list1[first-1]`?

Comment: not only python, all languages)

Comment: @user8426627: *not* all languages.

Comment: best way to fis is list1 = [0,1,2,3]

Comment: @ Scott Hunter in whitch one is different indexins?

Comment: @user8426627 many languages use 1-based indexing. R for example

Comment: @user8426627 : Pascal, for instance. In Perl it is settable at runtime by changing $[ from 0 to 1...

Comment: @user8426627: For example, Pascal allows for the range to be user-defined, so could start with whatever you wanted.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list

Comment: Back to the question, i don't know what you're really asking. If you understand how indexing works this should be no surprise

Comment: @user8426627 Fortran

Comment: `first` is the value of the first element of `list1`, not its index or key.

Comment: thanks for @hpaulj to light me up

Comment: @ScottHunter if you write your comment `list1 [first-1]` I'll mark it as true answer man

Comment: @hpaulj and sorry if its contain a reference to value of first element, why `list [first]` works too. like an index??

Comment: Set `list1 = [41,42,43,44]` and try your example again. You might understand then.

Comment: The value is `1`, which works as an index.  Try a different list, like `['a',34, 1.345, [1,2,3]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first` is set to 1, so normal to get the second element of the list. If `first` was set to 'spam' for instance, `list1[first]` would just fail:

```
>>> list1 = ["spam", "egg"]
>>> first, second = list1
>>> list1[first]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I suggest using a `dict` instead:

```
 >>> dict1 = {"first": 1, "second": 2}
 >>> dict1["first"]
 1
```

Comment: sorry i cant understand what you said?! what you mean about if `first` set to spam

Comment: and there is no way to use custom key like this in lists?

Comment: `list` by definition uses integers as key, starting to 0. `dict` is made for arbitrary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Because first holds the integer 1, so list1[first] is actually list1[1]

Comment: so is there any way to fix it? because type `first` only, return true value

Comment: i don't know what your purpose is. If you show me what you are trying to do, maybe I can help. For now it seems like you haven't look over the basics of python

Answer (score -1):

If you want your values in `list1` to be used as 1-based indices but don't want  to change `list1`, you could use (for example):

```
list1[first-1]
```